# Batching generation of http responses

Tags: performance, rest, http, architecture

I'm trying to find an architecture for the following scenario. I'm building a REST service that performs some computation that can be quickly batch computed. Let's say that computing 1 "item" takes 50ms, and computing 100 "items" takes 60ms.

However, the nature of the client is that only 1 item needs to be processed at a time. So if I have 100 simultaneous clients, and I write the typical request handler that sends one item and generates a response, I'll end up using 5000ms, but I know I could compute the same in 60ms.

I'm trying to find an architecture that works well in this scenario. I.e., I would like to have something that merges data from many independent requests, processes that batch, and generates the equivalent responses for each individual client.

If you're curious, the service in question is python+django+DRF based, but I'm curious about what kind of architectural solutions/patterns apply here and if anything solving this is already available.

Comment: Isn't this just about threads ? If the calculation wouldn't be that fast I would have suggested a Cache too

Answer (score 1):

At first you could think of a reverse proxy detecting all pattern-specific queries, collecting all theses queries and sending it to your application in an HTTP 1.1 **pipeline** (pipelining is a way to send a big number of queries one after another and receiving all HTTP responses in the same order at the end, without waiting for a response after each query).

But:

1. Pipelining is very hard to do well
2. you would have to code the reverse proxy as I do not know a way to do it
3. one slow response in the pipeline block all the other responses
4. you need an http server able to give several queries to your application language, something which never happens if the http server is not directly coded in your application, because usually http is made to work on only one query (like you never receive 2 queries in a PHP env, you receive the 1st one, send the response, and then receive the next one, even if the connection contain 2 queries).

So the good idea would be to do that **on the application side**. You could identify matching queries, and wait for a small amount of time (10ms?) to see if some other queries are also incoming. You will need a way to communicate between several parallel workers here (like you have 50 application workers and 10 of them have received queries that could be treated in the same batch). This way of communication could be a database (a very fast one) or some shared memory, depends on the technology used.

Then when too much time waiting has been spend (10ms?) or when a big amount of queries are received, one of the worker could collect all queries, run the batch, and tell every other workers that a result is there (here again you need a central point of communication, like LISTEN/NOTIFY in PostgreSQL, a shared memory thing, a message queue service, etc.).

Finally every worker is responsible for sending the right HTTP response.

The key here is having a system where **the time you loose** in trying to share requests treatment **is less important than the time saved** in batching several queries together, and in case of low traffic this time should stay reasonnable (as here you will always loose time waiting for nothing). And of course you are also adding some **complexity** on the system, harder to maintain, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I've been thinking of using message queues instead of database or shared memory, so the request handler can wait on the response.